# Schema Browser does not show fields added in schema.xml by me in Solr

Tags: tomcat, solr, lucene

I have added some fields in schema.xml of core named "Core3" created by me in solr v5.1. I am not referring to examples folder but using "server" folder to run solr server and to create solr cores.

I have created cores using "solr create" utility provided in bin folder.

I have created code name "Core3" using command,

```
solr create -c Core3
```

When I went and see in "C:\tomcat-solr\server\solr\Core3\conf" folder I did not find schema.xml so I copied schema.xml file from folder "\solr-5.1.0\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\conf".

I have added below fields.

```
 <field name="courseid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />   
   <field name="coursetitle" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>    
   <field name="durationinseconds" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />   
   <field name="releasedate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

After that I have stopped and started apache tomcat on which solr hosted and tried to see new fields in "Schema Browser" in Admin UI but these fields were not there. Kindly help me with reason why fields are not showing?

Comment: did you checked the schema of Core3 or some other core?

Comment: when I browse through the Admin UI and with different core then I get the URL as http://IP:port/solr/247/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema1.xml http://IP:port/solr/266/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema1.xml

Comment: When I go to URL, http://localhost:port/solr/#/Core3/files?file=schema.xml, it opens my schema xml file with added fields.

Comment: what was the issue earlier?

Comment: I still have issue. Despite showing schema.xml, it is not taking config settings from this file. :(

Comment: I m confused.. whats the issue earlier? Is it resolved and whats the issue now..?

Comment: It is straightforward. I have created a new core as mentioned in the questions. When I went to conf folder of this core, I did see schema.xml file then I have copied from other folder to "conf" folder of newly created core and added some fields as mentioned in the question but it is not reflecting in schema browser in Admin UI.

Comment: when you add the fields to new schema.xml. restart the tomcat server and check the changes to the specific core. as provided url in the above comment.

Comment: Kindly read my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the solrconfig.xml file in the conf folder located in the directory for your core. There is a way to define using a managed-schema or schema.xml for that core

To use schema.xml it says to set `<schemaFactory>` to...

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

To use the managed-schema file, which seems to be the default when you create a new core in this way (this file is not supposed to be hand edited but rather use the dynamic schema REST API to programmatically edit it) you would set it to...

```
<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
  <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
  <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
</schemaFactory>
```

More on this can be found here...
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managed+Schema+Definition+in+SolrConfig

Or there is explanation in the solrconfig.xml file itself near the schemaFactory section.